# Geometry of contracted divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, projective-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, rational-points

Let $f:\mathbb{P}^3\dashrightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ be a dominant rational map defined over a field $k$ (not necessarily algebraically closed) of characteristic zero.

Consider a resolution $\widetilde{f}:X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^2$ of $f$ and assume that a general fiber of $\widetilde{f}$ is the strict transform of a conic in $\mathbb{P}^3$ while $S = \widetilde{f}^{-1}([1:0:0])$ is a surface.

Under these hypotheses can we say something on the birational type of $S$? For instance assuming that $S$ has a point defined over the base field $k$ how far can $S$ be from being rational over $k$?

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That follows from "Abhyankar's lemma in birational geometry".  Provided that $X$ is normal, every irreducible divisor $E$ in $X$ that is contracted to a subvariety of the (regular) target having codimension $\geq 2$ in the target is ruled over its image (in the target).  You can read about this in the appendix to "Rational curves on algebraic varieties" by J'anos Koll'ar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface $S$ is uniruled. Indeed, considering $X$ as a family of conics in $\mathbb{P}^3$ parameterized by an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^2$, we obtain a rational map
$$
\phi \colon \mathbb{P}^2 \dashrightarrow 
\mathrm{Hilb}(\mathbb{P}^3)
$$
to the Hilbert scheme of conics in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Resolving this map by an appropriate blowup $\pi \colon Y \to \mathbb{P}^2$, we obtain a morphism
$$
\tilde\phi \colon Y \to \mathrm{Hilb}(\mathbb{P}^3).
$$
Moreover, if $Z \subset Y \times \mathbb{P}^3$ is the corresponding family of conics, the projection $\pi$ induces a surjective morphism $Z \to X$, such that
$$
Z_0 := Z \times_Y \pi^{-1}(0)
$$
dominates $S = X \times_{\mathbb{P}^2} \{0\}$. So, it remains to note that $Z_0 \to \pi^{-1}(0)$ is a family of conics.